Azure Data Factory: How do I create multiple destination folders from a list of files stored in a csv file?
I want to create multiple folders, each folder should bear a name from a list of names stored in a csv file. Say I have a csv file 'folderlist.csv' which contain list of files:
| files|
|:---- |
| freebees  |
| niclopass|
| matblob|
| rendertube|
| countbee|
I want to have destination folders with each name, years, and months.
Exaple:
freebees/freebees-2023/freebess-2023-0123,freebess-2023-0223,...,freebess-2023-1223
freebees/freebees-2024/freebess-2024-0124,freebess-2024-0224,...,freebess-2024-1224
...
niclopass/niclopass-2023/niclopass-2023-0123,niclopass-2023-0223,...,niclopass-2023-1223
niclopass/niclopass-2024/niclopass-2024-0124,niclopass-2024-0224,...,niclopass-2024-1224
...
... and so on.
So far, I created a lookup activity that looks up the folderlist.csv, a ForEach Loop that iterates the folder names. My idea is to pretend to copy files into the folder destinations and create those folder structures in the process. Any ideas will be really helpful

freebess-2023-0123,freebess-2023-0223,...,freebess-2023-1223 these are also folders?

Yes they are folders within freebess-2023

To achieve your requirement First we need absolute folder path to create each subfolder.

To get Absolute path for subfolders you need to use data flow.


First take Data flow and add dataset as your folderlist.csv with column delimiter as / so below is initial data looks like:

Then take derived column to split the last comma separated sub folders using split function.

Then take the flatten transformation to flatten the above subfolders column:

Then take another Derived column activity to concat all the required folders as below concat({_col0_},'/', {_col1_},'/' , subfolders):

Data preview:

Select the required columns using select Transformation:

Then store it in csv file.


Now using this above created file read the data with Lookup activity:

Pass the output of lookup activity to the For each activity.

Create Dummy file to use in Copy activity to create folder.


Under this For Each activity use copy activity to copy dummy file in destination.
Source Settings:

Add parameterized sink and add parameter as for each iterator column:

Then add delete activity to delete the dummy file from created folder.


